# What is the best way to add user ID to RubyOnRails log entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I am looking for the best way to customize my Rails log entries (I want to add the user ID in there). I am using Rails 2.1.2. The only way I've found so far is to override method "add" of class BufferedLogger (as defined in active_support/lib/active_support).

But it ain't pretty: I have to copy all the code in there and it is 
closely tied to the current implementation. Is there a better way? 
I found this on the Google: http://pandejo.blogspot.com/2007/08/customize-logger-message-format.html but it seems outdated. 
One day, I might create a specific audit log, but it is overkill for 
what I need: http://maintainable.com/articles/rails_logging_tips#audit-logs 
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the [user_event_logger](http://github.com/ffmike/user_event_logger/tree/master) plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You could just do logger.info in an after_filter in your application_controller:

```
after_filter :logging
 def logging
  if logger && logged_in?
   logger.info "UserID: #{current_user.id.to_s}"
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to capture, every action each user does, or just a specific sub-set of actions?  If a sub-set one quick and dirty way would be to simply use a logger call to dump the user-id to the log for the actions you want to track.

Comment: The former. We're trying to create a sort of audit trail. Your q&d approach has been ruled out.

Comment: take a look here: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=23540, to build a custom logger with it's own log file.

Comment: that link points to the same link as in the original question. "overkill" for now.